# angular-mocks ignoring request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular-mock

I am trying to use the `$httpBackend` service of Angular (v1.2.15) but it just ignores my request. As you see, I have planned two kind of requests, one for **html documents** and another one for **REST requests**. However, nothing happens when I do the request. I still receive the promise but will never be resolved. If I change the request and write something unexpected, I get a failure.

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('testApp', ['ngMockE2E'])
        .run(function ($httpBackend, $http) {

            $httpBackend.whenGET(new RegExp(".*\/rest\/data$")).respond(function() {
                return [200, {title: 1}, {}]
            });

            $httpBackend.whenGET(new RegExp(".*\\.html$")).passThrough();

            $http.get("/rest/data").finally(function() {
                console.log("Request mocked");
            });

        });

}(angular));
```

**Edit**:

Ok, I am going to show yout the steps I have followed to debug the error:

- I have used `passThrough` function instead of `respond` to check that the regex was correctly evaluated. And yes, it made the real request and obviously the response was Not Found.
- After that, I have checked flushing the request as already explained in the comments, but also received a message from angular saying that there were no requests.
- `console.log()` does not output anything either. Alerts, break points, etc. neither.

Any other ideas?

**Edit 2:**

Problem solved. Guess how. I restarted grunt server and worked directly.

I will try to reproduce the bug later to see if it must be reported

Answer (score 2):

Try flushing the pending requests.

```
$httpBackend.flush();
```

Comment: Hm, and you did it after `$http.get` i assume. Could it be that the regexp doesn't match? It looks OK but you could try with the exact string just in case.

Comment: Already did, and if I change the get request to a non-matching string I receive an error, unexpected GET request. It is just that $httpBackend is not resolving the promise for any reason

Comment: Then color me confused. I can't see the why it's not working. You should perhaps edit your question to include things you have tried (like `flush()`).

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of the title variable or shouldn't that be quoted? Me hating languages that silently fail. You are also missing a semicolon at the end of your return statement. there may be other javascript voodoo happening. recommend running it in a debugger like Chrome's to see what is actually happening.

You are also missing the mime-type header in your response.

Comment: `title` isn't a variable, it's a property name. Semi-colons are optional (though very much recommended) but the missing one here shouldn't be a problem. There are some corner-cases where a missing semicolon is problematic but this is not one of them.

Comment: If it's JSON it should be quoted.

Comment: You might be on to something, I took a look at the docs, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#when. "return an array containing response status (number), response data (string), response headers (Object), and the text for the status (string)." It seems the response payload is expected to be a string, not an Object.